# How to use a photomultiplier tube

Tags: power-electronics, photonics

I would like to use a photomultiplier tube to measure the light produced from cavitation for a project. How do I log the reading of this instrument?

Comment: A photomultiplier tube on its own requires a good bit of supporting circuitry, and *then* you can connect that circuitry to a datalogger. It's not something you can just power and use.

Answer (score 3):

Photomultiplier tubes are conceptually a lot like reverse biased photodiodes in operation, you apply a (very large) voltage across the tube and then when a photon hits the cathode, a pulse of current comes out the back.  If a lot of photons hit, you get a continuous current.  Either way, you convert that current to voltage and then read out the voltage.  Since the gain on a PMT can be so large, you may or may not need a transimpedance amplifier, sometimes a resistor alone is enough.

You can buy bare tubes in which case you must provide the high voltage circuitry to bias it, you can buy tube modules that include the high voltage potted inside which are much safer to work with, and finally complete detectors that have the high voltage and transimpedance stage integrated together.  You can also get different photocathode materials for different wavelengths, and it is very important that you pick correctly as the quantum efficiency of most materials is quite low, so even in the best case only a minority of photons are detected.

Finally it is worth pointing out that APD/SPAD/SiPM detectors are increasingly being used in place of photomultiplier tubes because they are much cheaper and often have higher quantum efficiency.  The disadvantage is that dark counts are often higher, so they don't work as well when recording small numbers of photons over a longer time period (low counts per second).  The cost difference can be very large, with PMTs often costing 1000-10000 USD, whereas a 1 mm square SPAD might cost 20 or 30 dollars and have twice the quantum efficiency (depending on wavelength), so it is worth carefully considering what detector type is best for your application.